# Simple updating string on single line / dynamic

Tags: python, dynamic

I'm brand new to Python and henceforth I am wanting to develop my knowledge of the language!

So recently I got a Raspberry Pi B+, and today I was working on a script in python that would update the temperature of its CPU in the terminal the same way the CPU usage percentage is updated in the **top** or **htop** utility

```
/opt/vc/bin/vcgencmd measure_temp
```

Entering and hitting return the above code in the console/ssh prints the temperature of the CPU in the form of:

```
temp=34.2'C
```

So my main goal was to have the above line continually updated automatically with perhaps a

```
time.sleep(2)
```

To delay the updating time.

It would be even better if you could get rid of the "temp=", which I believe we can accomplish by using `.replace()`

Thanks for any help!

Comment: would be better to use a string slice - basically if your line is in a string variable called `line`, you want to display `line[4:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To run the command every two seconds and to print `34.2°C` part:

```
import subprocess
import sys
import time

while True:
    time.sleep(2 - time.time() % 2) # lock with the timer, to avoid drift
    output = subprocess.check_output(["/opt/vc/bin/vcgencmd", "measure_temp"])
    t = output.rpartition('=')[2] # extract the part after the last '='
    sys.stderr.write("\r%6s" % t.strip())
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but, my goal here is to have it update just the single line and not have it print out the temperature every two seconds, I was already able to achieve the printing method.

Comment: @Stewiezzz: update your question and explain what "update just the single line" means. Do you want to suppress any output from the command? Do you want to save history of previous temperature values? Have you tried to run the code? How exactly does Its behavior differ from the desired one?

Comment: When you use the top or htop utility, a CPU usage percentage is displayed, this percentage is changed every second or so without being "printed" again and again. No, I'm not looking to save the values (at the moment). And yes I've tried running this code. Thanks

Comment: @Stewiezzz: I've updated the answer to print inplace.

Comment: @Stewiezzz: there might have been a newline left in the output. I've added `.strip()` to remove it. Another possibility is that the child process writes to stderr. Redirect it to stdout in this case: add `stderr=subprocess.STDOUT` to `check_output()` call.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change output format, you should do it in the script `measure_temp`.
Now what you need is :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#-*- coding:utf-8 -*-

import os
import time

while 1:
    os.system('/opt/vc/bin/vcgencmd measure_temp')
    time.sleep(2)
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: `os.system()` does not capture the output.

Comment: I was already able to achieve what your code achieves, my goal here is to have it update just the single line and not have it print out the temperature every two seconds, thanks for the answer though!

Answer (score 1):

I know this is not in scope, but have you looked at the watch command. 
Why reinvent the wheel if you don't have to.

```
watch --help

Usage:
 watch [options] command

Options:
  -b, --beep             beep if command has a non-zero exit
  -c, --color            interpret ANSI color sequences
  -d, --differences[=<permanent>]
                         highlight changes between updates
  -e, --errexit          exit if command has a non-zero exit
  -g, --chgexit          exit when output from command changes
  -n, --interval <secs>  seconds to wait between updates
  -p, --precise          attempt run command in precise intervals
  -t, --no-title         turn off header
  -x, --exec             pass command to exec instead of "sh -c"

 -h, --help     display this help and exit
 -v, --version  output version information and exit

For more details see watch(1).
```

Try watch ls -l  or watch date

Comment: Added watch --help to the answer.

Comment: Yes this does the job! However I can't set this as the accepted answer, as Sebastian's answer to my question made it possible using python. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to display the text after the `=`, it would be better to use a string slice rather than replace.
If your line is in a string variable called `line`, you want to display `line[5:]`, i.e. from character 5 to the end - python strings start from character 0 (in your case the `t`).